# Navigate through a big array of similiar objects

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

My iOS application needs to support navigation between views which represent objects from an array. The array is ordered and it may contain up to 1000 objects. The navigation has to be like `UINavigationController` does, i.e each view has to provide user with ctrls to move to the next and prev object's view. The movement between views must be done with an animated transition. The content of each view is the same.

I understand and know how to do it with `UINavigationController`. My concern is that `UINavigationController` holds a stack of `UIViewControllers` and it will be rather big for the last element.

Is it possibly to hold only one `UIViewController` to display current object  object and mock the `UINavigationController's` transition behavior to the next and prev object ? So I would like just to change object inside UIViewController mock `UINavigationController's` transition and update UIViewController content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My concern is that UINavigationController holds a stack of UIViewControllers and it will be rather big for the last element.

Don't optimize prematurely! View controllers are lightweight. *Views* are heavyweight, but the views of all the view controllers except the "top" (visible) view controller in a navigation controller are not in the interface, so they have no backing store and take up little memory. And if there is a memory problem, then there's an easy solution: manipulate the UINavigationController's "stack" of view controllers directly to remove intermediate view controllers. (See the [UINavigationController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) to learn how to do this.)

On the other hand, I have to say that your entire architecture sounds like a much better candidate for a UIPageViewController than for a UINavigationController. UIPageViewController is exactly meant for moving to previous or successive "pages" in a "book" arrangement, and the wonderful thing is that only *one* view controller exists at any given moment (or, at most, three - if you use the "scroll" style of page view controller, the previous and next view controller always exist, automatically, so that scrolling to them is fast).

Comment: I think it is a typical task (for example, show pages from a book), and I don't think it's right to hold 1000 equal uiviewcontroller when you can just use only one, currently i have intermediate solution based on transitionFromViewController which uses only two uiviewcontroller, but I think there is a better approach

Comment: Is the uiviewcontroller.view is released when it is not on top of uinavigationcontroller's stack ?

Comment: 1000 is certainly different from 100, which is what you originally said. And if you mean pages from a book, why did you not say so? I've modified my answer to give a better solution.

Comment: And see my book if you need an introduction to UIPageViewController: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_page_view_controller

Comment: it was my mistake, actually it can be even bigger, actually it is not a book but it is a good example of what  I would like to achieve, i.e I've got only one presentation for each object from an array and I need just to switch between objects with an animated transition

Comment: @sim Fine, my answer stands.

Comment: UIPageViewController did the trick, thanks, I was thinking about it but I quickly switched to UINavigationController, probably, because the key word here was 'navigation'.

Comment: It's "navigation" as in UINavigationBar. As a rule of thumb, if you don't need the nav bar, you don't need the navigation controller. That is not totally true; it's really the navigation "stack" owned by the navigation bar (and the navigation controller). And you don't need or want that.